# Downloading images in the background issue displaying

Tags: android, android-imageview

what I am currently doing is allowing users to look up tracks, it will display the song name and display the artist and then start downloading the images in the background so that the user sees the results quickly. What I currently do is take the first 10 queries and dislpay those and download those images, then when the user clicks show more it will download 10 more and so on, but the only image that actually displays once it is done loading is the first one. The rest of the images download, but the imageviews do not populate unless i scroll away from them and then back over them. I can't figure out why, but here is my code.

My code for the custom list adapter:

```
public class SearchSongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> track_info;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    String token;
    ArrayList<ImageView> imageViews;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> imageBitMaps;
    DownloadImageTask downloadImageTask;
    int downloadsCounter = 0;
    public SearchSongAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> track_info, String token)
    {
        imageViews = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
        imageBitMaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.track_info = track_info;
        this.token = token;
        //start the downloads
        if(track_info.size() > 0) {
            downloadImageTask = new DownloadImageTask();
            downloadImageTask.execute("https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/" + track_info.get(0).get(1).replace("spotify:track:", ""), String.valueOf(downloadsCounter));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.track_info.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return track_info.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView songNameTextView, artistNameTextView;
        ImageView trackIconImageView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView;
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song_list_items, null);
        holder.songNameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
        holder.artistNameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.artistNameTextView);
        holder.trackIconImageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.trackIconImageView);

        holder.songNameTextView.setText(track_info.get(position).get(0));
        holder.artistNameTextView.setText(track_info.get(position).get(2));

        imageViews.add(position, holder.trackIconImageView);
        if(position < imageBitMaps.size()) {
            holder.trackIconImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitMaps.get(position));
        }

        return rowView;
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        int position;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            HttpResponse response = null;
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String albumpicture;
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            position = Integer.valueOf(urls[1]);

            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Accept", "application/json"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization Bearer ", token));

            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                // writing response to log
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                    albumpicture = jsonObject.getJSONObject("album").getJSONArray("images").getJSONObject(0).getString("url");
                    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(albumpicture).openStream();
                    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    mIcon11 = getResizedBitmap(mIcon11, 50, 50);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            imageViews.get(position).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageBitMaps.add(position, bitmap);
            if(position < track_info.size() - 1) {
                downloadImageTask = new DownloadImageTask();
                downloadImageTask.execute("https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/" + track_info.get(downloadsCounter).get(1).replace("spotify:track:", ""), String.valueOf(downloadsCounter));
            }
            downloadsCounter++;

        }
    }
```

DownloadImageTask is where I download the image and I first call it in the constructor.

Summary:
The first imageView loads and populates, but the others do not populate unless I scroll away from there (scroll down) and then back up.

Comment: kindly check this example, how listview is populated with imgaeView in it, https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activities/list/first/CustomListViewActivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rockyfish,

you can reduce your hustle about loading the `Images` and managing the network call all by your self.

your loading image logic can be replaced by one line of code like this.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image_url).into(holder.trackIconImageView);

where,

getApplicationContext() ===> is context which can be replaced with context you you are assigning to the `adapter` 

image_url =================> is the url to the imgae,
```

the process of loading the ImgaeView from a image kept at some url is done by `Picasso` as you know he is a great painter so let him do the work.

to add the `Picasso` library  adding following code to the dependencies block in the `build.gradle` file like this

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

and you would be able to use `picasso`

Answer (score 0):

We have awesome open source libraries to handle the image download and caching stuff - [Picasso Square](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

We should always try to use existing and proven solutions rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.